# How do I delete a previous OS and expand my current OS partition?

Tags: partitioning, kde

I installed Manjaro then installed Ubuntu KDE on a second partition. I've decided I prefer Ubuntu and would like to delete the Manjaro partition and expand the Ubuntu.

Using KDE Partition Manager (see image), do I simply delete sda2, then move/resize sda3 by specifying 0 bytes before? I'm worried about screwing this up and ending up with a dead system.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When resizing a partition you need to consider to which side the partition will grow, if you want to grow to the right for example, you don't need sda3 and want sda2 to use that space the solution is deleting sda3 and resizing sda2, but in your case you want to resize sda3 to the left(taking sda2 space), the solution for this is more involved:

**BEFORE THIS CREATE A BACKUP OF YOUR DATA**

1. Boot in to a live iso with gparted installed.
2. Delete the windows partition (sda2)
3. move the ubuntu partition to the left(sda3) **DO NOT RESIZE THE PARTITION YET**
4. once the move operation is complete you can resize the partition to the right.
5. if you are using a bios system then recreate the GRUB install, but if you are using an EFi system this step is not required.

and that's it.

**NOTE: UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCE CANCEL OR STOP THE MOVE OR RESIZE OPERATIONS OR YOU WILL LOSE ALL YOUR DATA!**

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. What's the best method for backing up my existing system partition: Clonezilla or the KDE Partition Editor's "Backup Partition" function (or something else)?

Comment: clonezilla will create a backup of your entire disk instead of just only the partition table, so if you want to be safe use clonezilla, for that you need a disk of at least the same size as your current disk

Comment: Worked like a champ. Thanks!